# Replace only special characters which are in groups using JQuery

Tags: jquery, string, replace

I need to output the expanded notation of an IPv6 address such as `2001:db8:a0b:12f0::1/48` to  `2001:db8:a0b:12f0:0000:0000:1/48`. As you can see, only where there are 2 `::` that needs to be replaced with `:0000:0000:`.

I tried to do it but every `:` is getting replaced with `:0000:0000:`.

These are the codes:

**Codes**

```
var inputString = ip,
outputString = inputString.replace(/([:: ])+/g, ':0000:0000:').replace(/^(-)+|(-)+$/g,'');
console.log(outputString);
$("#prefix").attr("value",outputString);
```

Any help please? Thanks.

Comment: `inputString.replace(/(::)+/g, ':0000:0000:')` this will do it.

Comment: You are using a character group ("any of these characters in brackets") `[: ]` which "repeats one or more times": `+`. You probably want "repeats two or more times": `{2,}` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @Piskvor.

Comment: @Jai Thanks it works. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try with `/(::)+/g` as it creates a group for two colons:

```js
var str    = '2001:db8:a0b:12f0::1/48', 
    newStr = str.replace(/(::)+/g, ':0000:0000:');

document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = newStr;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```